# Count largest duplicate in a list of cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a list of cells which contain values (A,B,C,D,E...). I'd like to count the largest duplicate.
I think about multiple MAX together with COUNTIF but that would be very long since my list of value has 60+ items

Example file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZUnSokdPsEPVJw9S8DfGHvJE1L1Ng8litbCXeA9QWzI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I'm new at this, but I think the following formula does what you've asked.

```
=INDEX(A2:G2,MODE(MATCH(A2:G2,A2:G2,0)))
```

Your sheet is view only, so I can't place it there.
Replace my A2:G2 range in the formula with the range with your long list (either column or row) of values.

This will search the range for the amount of the most duplicates, and return the first value that is duplicated the most.
Note: it doesn't flag if there are other values that have an equal number of duplciates as the first value.

Here is a sample sheet, with examples using values in a row, or in a column:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mIxTKXjED9kpqAGV55pf8Yjq102Sc5Ymn_yY6qh3XmE/edit?usp=sharing

Let me know if this doesn't achieve what you want.